# Keras - How to get only one tensor from a batch of tensors?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I have a batch of tensors of shape `?,192`. Now I want to get any single random tensor from this batch. 
the resulting tensor should have the shape of `1,192`, note that this should be done in Keras.
Any idea of how to get this done?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @dspencer I tried to use lambda function. this way `var= Lambda(lambda x: x[:1,:])(var)`, and it didn't work

Comment: Is your tensor shape (None, 192)? If so, the tensor shape is actually (192,), meaning 192 neurons, the None in front means the batch size.

Comment: Yes, I know that. I was trying to take only one tensor from this batch. The problem was solved by using a tensorflow operation with a lambda function like this 
`Var= Lambda(lambda inputs: tf.gather_nd(inputs, [[0]]) )(Var)`
Thank you for commenting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved with a tensorflow operation with a lambda function

```
Var= Lambda(lambda inputs: tf.gather_nd(inputs, [[0]]) )(Var)
```